# Why do I get the sentence I don't want? and how to correct it?

Tags: python

I'm learning programming over there and I have a "challenge" to do, its super basic...

"You must take an exam with three questions that you generate, the user must only answer yes or no. At the end you must give him a grade (starting from 0 and for each correct answer you increase by 1)"

and I have this:

```
name = input("What's your name: ")

print(f'Welcome {name} to the question challenge')

print('Question number 1 (answer YES or NO)')

answer1 = input('My favorite color is purple:')

if answer1 == 'Yes' or 'si' or 'SI' or 'sI':
    print(f'You are right')
    number = 0 
    print(number)
    number += 1
    print(number)

elif answer1 == 'No' or 'NO' or 'no' or 'nO':
    print('You got it wrong')
    number = 0

else:
    print('Please answer with YES or NO')
```

When I want to activate the phrase "elif" or "else" I get the "if" (You are right) sentence. I don't know what to do to get the 'elif' or 'else' sentence

thanks

Comment: This form `answer1 == 'Yes' or 'si' or 'SI' or 'sI'` doesn't work.  It would be `answer1 == 'Yes' or answer1 == 'si' or answer1== 'SI' or answer1 == 'sI'`

Comment: Thank you all, I am not English speaking so I put "SI" or "sI", because my code is written in Spanish and I was lazy to translate all the "Si", however, your answers served me well thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain strings like "si" evaluate to True.

```
>>> bool('si')
True
```

Instead use the in operator.

```
if answer1 in {'Yes', 'si', 'SI', 'sI'}:
    print(f'You are right')
    number = 0 
    print(number)
    number += 1
    print(number)

elif answer1 in {'No', 'NO', 'no', 'nO'}:
    print('You got it wrong')
    number = 0

else:
    print('Please answer with YES or NO')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that in the checks, say this one `if answer1 == 'Yes' or 'si' or 'SI' or 'sI':` you are first comparing to see if `answer1` is equal to `'Yes'`, but then when you write `or 'si'`, you are not comparing it to the `answer1` variable, but rather you check for the truthness of the `'si'` string.

Strings, except for the empty one `''` evaluate to `True` in Python, thus the condition is always evaluated in your case to `True` and never gets to `elif` or `else`. The same is for the `elif` you should change it there.

As @alec pointed out, you may use sets for more clear code here. Like the following `if answer1 in {'Yes', 'si', 'SI', 'sI'}:` or you can use a separate check for each possible answer, such as `if answer1 == 'Yes' or answer1 == 'si':`

It is also a good idea to convert the answer to lowercase not to compare it with all the possible combinations. Another advice I'd give is to declare the `numbers` variable outside the `if` scope.

Here is a possible solution:

```py
name = input('What\'s your name: ')

print(f'Welcome {name} to the question challenge')

correct_answers = 0

print('Question number 1 (answer YES or NO)')


answer1 = input('My favorite color is purple:')

if answer1.lower() in {'yes', 'si'}:
    print(f'You are right')
    correct_answers += 1
    print(correct_answers)
elif answer1.lower() == 'no':
    print('You got it wrong')
else:
    print('Please answer with YES or NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your use of the `or` operator. The following statement will *always* evaluate to `True`.

```
if x == 'something' or 'something else':
```

Since this is equivalent to:

```
if (x == 'something') or (bool('something else')):
```

And `bool('anything')` is equivalent to `True`. What you probably *meant* to do is:

```
if x == 'something' or x == 'something else':
```

But you can use the `in` operator to make this shorter:

```
if x in ('something', 'something else'):
```

And to avoid the various checks for case-sensitivity, it might be worthwhile to think about using the `lower()` function.

So putting it all together:

```
if answer1.lower() in ('yes', 'si'):
    print('You are right')
    number = 0 
    print(number)
    number += 1
    print(number)

elif answer1.lower() in ('no',): # This trailing comma is on purpose.
    print('You got it wrong')
    number = 0

else:
    print('Please answer with YES or NO')
```